# C# class wrapper for a distributable dll

Tags: c#, dll, wrapper

I have a C# library that I'd like to make distributable with a wrapper dll that provides a bit more functionality than the class itself.

I'd like to be able to create an object from the class library and use it with the wrapper dll in another project like so:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      var wrapper = new Wrapper(); // my wrapper dll class
      var classLib = new ClassLib(1, "test", ..); // create class from my library
      wrapper.Send(classlib); // method in my wrapper
     }
 }
```

I can do this if I include my wrapper dll and the class library dll in the project. However, I'd like to be able to have 1 distributable dll to accomplish this. Is there a way to do the above without including a redefinition of my class library class in the wrapper?

Hope this is somewhat clear. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can merge multiple .NET assemblies into one using [**ILMerge**](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-B4AD-4EAE-87CF-B14AE6A939B0&displaylang=en). Typically you would call ILMerge in the post-build step of your project.